# Big O Notation - O(N) Fibonacci Generator

Tags: big-o, fibonacci, memoization

Just brushing up on my big O in advance of an interview.

On pages 53 and 54 of cracking the coding interview (6th ed), in the chapter on big O, you will see example 15, which appears as follows.

```
void allFib(int n){
    int[] memo = new int[n+1];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        System.out.println(i + ":" + fib(i,memo));
    }
}

int fib(int n, int[] memo){
    if(n<=0) return 0;
    else if(n==1) return 1;
    else if(memo[n]>0) return memo[n];

    memo[n]=fib(n-1,memo)+fib(n-2,memo);

    return memo[n];
}
```

Long story short, this is a standard approach, which uses memoisation to ensure fib values only have to be calculated once.  But they still have to be calculated once and calculating them is O(2^N) temporal complexity.

The book is saying that because we can retrieve the fib values in constant time from the memo that the algorithm is O(N).

It does not explain why it is we can ignore the fact that you do have to derive the values once from an exponential function.  Is amortisation being applied?

I trust the book, but the explanation provided isn't helping me to understand why the temporal complexity is O(N) in this case.

**Post Edit:**

Let me put this another way.

How could calling fib n times be O(N)...
    int[] memo = new int[n+1];

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    System.out.println(i + ":" + fib(i,memo));
}
```

...when calling it once is O(N^2)?

```
fib(n,memo)
```

**Final Edit:**
Thanks all.  I have my answer.  Even the single call to the fib method benefits from memoisation and thus is not O(N^2), it too is O(N).

Comment: You've gotta be careful about what N is here.  `allFib(n)` is in **O(n)**, where **n** is the number you pass it.  It is *not* in **O(N)** where **N** is the size of the input (in bits).

Comment: Of course, the best way to do it is to use iteration rather than recursion.

Comment: Still not sure I understand.  If I call fib(n,memo) directly I have to work out fib(1), fib(2), fib(3)... fib(n).  That would be O(N^2) just like the non-memoised version because the memo is empty.  Adding a loop to call the function over and over again adds more work, not less.  You still have to calculate fib(1), fib(2)... fib(n), but then you have the constant time work to add and retrieve values from the memo.  In both cases the definition of n is the number you parse it as opposed to the size of an input in bits.

Comment: Makes sense now, see the final edit and David Soroko's answer.

Comment: Frankly, I would not give you the job when you come up with such a solution. The iterative approach is much simpler and straight forward.

Comment: The point of the exercise is to explore algorithmic implications of a particular approach. Not to write production code for Fibonacci.

Comment: That's OK Henry, I wouldn't hire someone with your reading comprehension skills either.

Answer (score 1):

One way to look at this is that in `memo[n]=fib(n-1,memo)+fib(n-2,memo)`
when `fib(n-1, memo)` returns, the value needed by `fib(n-2,memo)` is already stored in `memo` ( `if(memo[n]>0) return memo[n]` ), this is repeated at every recursion level.

So instead of the call graph looking like this (for the naive version):

```
        *
       * *
      * * * * 
  * * * * * * * *
```

It looks like this

```
         *
        * * 
       * *   
      * *
```

Comment: Lets say we call the second method above for n=50.  There is no loop calling it 50 times, just the recursion.  This is O(N^2) because the memo isn't useful.  It is empty at the start and the stored values are never re-visited.  Now call the first method with 50.  It loops from 1 to 50, calling fib(n) 50 times.  Each time it calls it, it is doing less work than the previous experiment, but it is calling it 50 times... plus the O(1) overhead of adding and retrieving from the memo.  More work, not less, and yet it is O(N)?

Comment: When you start with `memo[50]=fib(49,memo)+fib(48,memo)` the "first" thing to execute is the left hand call: fib(49,memo), then fib(48,memo),  fib(47,memo), etc... When this call chain (of depth 50) starts to return, the right hand call is executed at every step and returns immediately because the value has been already memoized

Comment: Thanks David.  That makes sense.  So even if I only call the fib method once with a large n value, it would still benefit from memoisation.

Answer (score 0):

It's `O(N)` because you only calculate each value once and reuse the calculated value later. E.g. for `fib(4)` this would be the call stack:

```
fib(4) = fib(3) + fib(2);
    fib(3) = fib(2) + fib(1);
        fib(2) = fib(1) + fib(0); // value stored
            fib(1) = 1;
            fib(0) = 1;
    fib(2) = 2; // value accessed
```

The stored value is accessed when it's already calculated.

When you have a look a look at the "lazy implementation" of the Fibonacci numbers:

```
int fib(int i) {
    if(i <= 1) return 1;
    return fib(i - 1) + fib(i - 2);
}
```

You need to calculate a lot of numbers more than once. E.g. again for `fib(4)` the call stack would look like:

```
fib(4) = fib(3) + fib(2);
    fib(3) = fib(2) + fib(1);
        fib(2) = fib(1) + fib(0);
            fib(1) = 1;
            fib(0) = 1;
    fib(2) = fib(1) + fib(0);
        fib(1) = 1;
        fib(0) = 1;
```

As you can see, `fib(2)`, `fib(1)` and `fib(0)` need to be calculated more than once. With your memory approach, you only calculate each new value once. Also, keep in mind that the call stack gets exponentially bigger with higher Fibonacci values which leads to even more "double calculation" of numbers. That's why this lazy approach has `O(2^N)` and the memory approach is `O(N)`.

HTH